# RGEE: calculate per pixel maximum NDVI value in a given year

Tags: r, google-earth-engine, ndvi, rgee

I'm trying to use RGEE to get the yearly maximum NDVI value per pixel. The code I've written however outputs an image consisting of the maximum NDVI value within the whole region (see image below), but not the per pixel maximum NDVI. Does anybody knows why this is happening?

```
library(rgee)
library(sf)

ee_Initialize(drive = TRUE)

#load ecoregio Kempen shapefile
Kempen <- st_read("./Ecoregio_Kempen.shp")  %>% st_transform(4326) %>% sf_as_ee()
region <- Kempen$geometry()$bounds()

s2 <- ee$ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")

getNDVI <- function(image) {
  ndvi <- image$normalizedDifference(c("B8", "B4"))$rename('NDVI')
  return(image$addBands(ndvi))
}

s2_NDVI <- s2$
  filterBounds(region)$
  filter(ee$Filter$lte("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 10))$
  filter(ee$Filter$date('2020-01-01', '2021-01-01'))$map(getNDVI)$max()

s2_NDVI <- s2_NDVI$select('NDVI')

s2_ic_local <- ee_image_to_drive(
  image = s2_NDVI,
  region = region,
  fileFormat = "GEO_TIFF",
  fileNamePrefix = 'Kempen_NDVI_2020'
)

s2_ic_local$start()
ee_monitoring(s2_ic_local)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was that I didn't provide an output CRS when exporting the image to my drive.